Is there a way to hide and password protect a Macbook menu bar item? Or permanently remove it from the menu bar? Not nefarious, I swear :)
I am using a NextDNS to filter web traffic for my family's devices. NextDNS currently shows in the menu bar and can be toggled on and off with a simple click, which defeats the entire purpose of the tool.
I have tried using a combination of Vanilla (to hide the menu bar item) and AppLocker (to require credentials to access an app, in this case, Vanilla). However, Vanilla has an option in the menu bar to access Vanilla's settings that is not blocked by AppLocker, therefore allowing NextDNS toggle menu bar icon to still be accessed.
Back to square one I guess.
On my Macbook Air MacOS Monterey, there are other ways to configure NextDNS (network settings, terminal commands, profiles), but because I am also using ProtonVPN, it appears Proton and NextDNS only coincide seamlessly when NextDNS is installed via the app store. The app store version of NextDNS is the one that puts a toggle switch in the menu bar :/
I would like to permanently remove the NextDNS menu bar icon and/or password protect the NextDNS menu bar icons modifications. It would need to be permanent, as in either not needing to be redone every restart or done in a way that it is automatically triggered on startup. Any thoughts on this?
I also asked ChatGPT and it suggested writing an AppleScript and some other options, but it was not quite clear enough for me to pull off.
Thanks for any help :)

I hope someone has a direct fix for you, if not there’s network level solutions if the devices stay under your WiFi umbrella. https://pbxbook.com/other/pstubby.html

@bmike that's a good idea. I actually forgot about it, but I actually have NextDNS configured on my router. Although I think that's a bit different from your suggestion. The only reason I mention it is that it seems NextDNS only works along with ProtonVPN when using the app version. For example, I have a Twitter blocked, but when I disable NextDNS app version, NextDNS router version, profiles, or network settings option dont seem to retain NextDNS setup. As if ProtonVPN is "going around" it? I'm not an IT specialist, so this stuff is beyond me.

VPN will get you past any local DNS control so even a local pi hole won’t work. You will need to rethink your setup…

@bmike interestingly enough, where I mentioned blocking Twitter with NextDNS, when I have NextDNS enabled via the app store, blocking Twitter via NextDNS works while also using ProtonVPN.

Glad bartender did the trick. Awesome piece of software

Instead of Vanilla you can consider using Bartender.
You can hide the NextDNS menu bar icon easily with it.
Once hidden you can assign a very complex Keyboard Shortcut through Bartender that will show the icon. This way you will be the only person who can see & access the app.

This is a very creative solution! I had already messed with Bartender a little bit and thought it was a no go.
